# Angular unit testing getting failed

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, karma-jasmine, angular-unit-test

I am trying to unit test the function `editDependentInfo()`, but I am getting error, because in that function, another function `populateEditDepInfo()` is being called and `populateEditDepInfo` have `this.dependentsInfo` property and test from `EditDependentInfo` is trying to access but not able to
Please find the below code and let me know what should I do

```
let dependentsInfo: Dependents;
        class ProfileDependentsStub {
            dependentInfoChange: Subject<any[]> = new Subject<any[]>();
            dependentInfoDelete: Subject<any[]> = new Subject<any[]>();

            data = {
                body: [{states: [{name: "Alabama", code: "AL"}]}, {countries: [{name: "UNITED STATES", code: "USA"}]}, ['relationshipType'], {hideDBCardStatus:"no"}, {hsaenrollmentStatus: "Enrolled"},{beneficiaryType:["Contingent", "Primary"]},
                {relationshipType:["Adopted Child"]}, {status:["Active"]}, 
                {prefixlist: ["DEACON"]},{prefixlist: ["DEACON"]}, {addressDetails:[{addressLineOne: "6226 3RD DRIVE"}]}, {beneficiaryList:[{id:123, firstName:"David"}]},
                {dependentsList:[{id:1234, employeeId:909}]} ]}

            getChildObject = function (href) {
                return { href: '' };
            };

            getChildLinks = function () {
                return Observable.of(ResponseData);
            };

            getLabelList = function (label) {
                return label;
            };

            addChildObjects = function (links) {
                return links;
            };

            addLabelList = function (labels) {
                return labels;
            };

            getStateCountryList = function () {
                return Observable.of(this.data);
            };

            getRelationAndStatusList = function () {
                return Observable.of(this.data);
            };

            getPrefixSuffixList = function () {
                return Observable.of(this.data);
            };

            populateEditDepInfo = function(data){
                return data;
            }

            getDependentsInfoDetails = function () {
                this.data.body['dependentsList'] = new Array('John Smith');
                return Observable.of(this.data);
            };
        }
```

test which is getting failed

```
  it('should edit Dependent Info', () => {

        component.editDependentInfo(null,this.userDependentInfo)

        expect(component.isUpdateDependentInfo).toBeTruthy();
    });
```

Component which I am testing

```
    export class {
       dependentsInfo: Dependents;
    editDependentInfo(event = null, userDependentInfo: Dependents) {
            this.dependentsInfo = <Dependents>{};
            this.clearSelectValues();
            this.isUpdateDependentInfo = true;
            this.dependentsInfo = userDependentInfo;
            this.populateEditDepInfo();
        }

        populateEditDepInfo(): void {
            this.saveDepInfo = false;
            if (this.dependentsInfo.id) {
                this.dependentId = this.dependentsInfo.id;
            }}
}
```

Sample Dependents class

```
class Dependents {
  name: string;
  id: string;
  dependentType: string;
  status: string;
  ineligibleReason: String;
  depndtDebitCardStatus: string;
  showCardStatusfInfo: boolean;
  addressLineOne: string;
  addressLineTwo: string;
  addressLineThree: string;
  city: string;}
```

Error which I am getting

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at ProfileDependentsViewComponent.populateEditDepInfo (webpack:///./src/app/profile/_profile-dependents-view/profile-dependents-view.component.ts?:207:33)
    at ProfileDependentsViewComponent.editDependentInfo (webpack:///./src/app/profile/_profile-dependents-view/profile-dependents-view.component.ts?:202:14)
    at Object.eval (webpack:///./src/app/profile/_profile-dependents-view/profile-dependents-view.component.spec.ts?:135:19)
```

Comment: You need to create a new instance of Dependents and pass that as a second argument to the component.editDependentInfo method call in your test, right now you are passing this.userDependentInfo which in that context is undefined

Comment: I tried putting like this but gives me an error.........
                                                                                                                                
          let Dependents =  {
        name: string;
        id: string;
        dependentType: string;
        status: string;
        ineligibleReason: String;
        depndtDebitCardStatus: string;
        showCardStatusfInfo: boolean;
        addressLineOne: string;
        addressLineTwo: string;}

Comment: You need to create an instance of that object, there you are just defining the types of every object attribute.

Comment: Can you add the test spec also.(full test file)

Comment: <div class="claims-side-panel"  [ngClass]="{'verticalOffset': <= 117? position:fixed}>

Comment: <div class="claims-side-panel" [ngClass]="{'this.verticalOffset': <= 117? 'position':'fixed'}">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below solution worked for me

```
it('should edit Dependent Info', () => {
let userDependentInfo= {  name: "john", ......}  as any

        component.editDependentInfo(null,this.userDependentInfo)

        expect(component.isUpdateDependentInfo).toBeTruthy();
    });
```